# Thoughtworks Cruise

Tags: active-directory, ldap, thoughtworks-cruise

I am having a difficult time trying to set up Cruise (not cruise control) by Thoughtworks to use active directory authentication. Can someone give me an example using LDAP/Active Directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the server config XML, within the server tag, add

```
 <security>
          <ldap uri="ldap://DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_URL" managerDn="CN=USER_THAT_CAN_LOGIN,OU=GROUP,DC=example,DC=com" managerPassword="PASSWORD" searchBase="OU=GROUP,DC=example,DC=com" searchFilter="(sAMAccountName={0})" />
</security
```

The most important part is the **searchFilter="(sAMAccountName={0})"** .

The **managerDn** is the user that can search for other users

The **OU** is the group that user belongs to

The **DC** is the domain